# Get pixel's RGB using PIL

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, rgb, pixel

Is it possible to get the RGB color of a pixel using PIL?
I'm using this code:

```
im = Image.open("image.gif")
pix = im.load()
print(pix[1,1])
```

However, it only outputs a number (e.g. `0` or `1`) and not three numbers (e.g. `60,60,60` for R,G,B). I guess I'm not understanding something about the function. I'd love some explanation.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 211, accepted):

Yes, this way:

```
im = Image.open('image.gif')
rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')
r, g, b = rgb_im.getpixel((1, 1))

print(r, g, b)
(65, 100, 137)
```

The reason you were getting a single value before with `pix[1, 1]` is because GIF pixels refer to one of the 256 values in the GIF color palette.

See also this SO post: [Python and PIL pixel values different for GIF and JPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800009/python-and-pil-pixel-values-different-for-gif-and-jpeg) and this [PIL Reference page](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm)  contains more information on the `convert()` function.

By the way, your code would work just fine for `.jpg` images.

Comment: Can this be done for the computer screen, and not just an image file?

Comment: Is Image.getpixel() 0-based or 1-based? I mean, the upper-left-most pixel is (0,0) or is it (1, 1)?

Comment: @NimaBavari It is 0-based.

Answer (score 9):

With numpy :

```
im = Image.open('image.gif')
im_matrix = np.array(im)
print(im_matrix[0][0])
```

Give RGB vector of the pixel in position (0,0)

Answer (score 4):

GIFs store colors as one of x number of possible colors in a palette. Read about the [gif limited color palette](http://www.prepressure.com/library/file-formats/gif). So PIL is giving you the palette index, rather than the color information of that palette color.

***Edit:*** Removed link to a blog post solution that had a typo. Other answers do the same thing without the typo.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to converting the image is to create an RGB index from the palette.

```
from PIL import Image

def chunk(seq, size, groupByList=True):
    """Returns list of lists/tuples broken up by size input"""
    func = tuple
    if groupByList:
        func = list
    return [func(seq[i:i + size]) for i in range(0, len(seq), size)]


def getPaletteInRgb(img):
    """
    Returns list of RGB tuples found in the image palette
    :type img: Image.Image
    :rtype: list[tuple]
    """
    assert img.mode == 'P', "image should be palette mode"
    pal = img.getpalette()
    colors = chunk(pal, 3, False)
    return colors

# Usage
im = Image.open("image.gif")
pal = getPalletteInRgb(im)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not PIL, but [`imageio.imread`](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scipy.html?highlight=imread) might still be interesting:

```
import imageio
im = scipy.misc.imread('um_000000.png', flatten=False, mode='RGB')
im = imageio.imread('Figure_1.png', pilmode='RGB')
print(im.shape)
```

gives

```
(480, 640, 3)
```

so it is (height, width, channels). So the pixel at position `(x, y)` is

```
color = tuple(im[y][x])
r, g, b = color
```

### Outdated

[`scipy.misc.imread`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html) is [deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/6242) (thanks for the reminder, [fbahr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/429303/fbahr)!)

Comment: PSA: `scipy.misc.imread` is deprecated! `imread` is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.2.0. Use `imageio.imread` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, fbahr! (I actually was involved in deprecating it - https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/6242  )