# Using Matplotlib imshow to show GIF image

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I need to show a background to a matplotlib plot using `ax.imshow()`. The background images that I will be using are GIF-images. Despite having PIL installed, the following code results in an error complaining that the Python Image Library (PIL) is not installed (which it is):

```
from pylab import imread
im_file = open("test.gif")
im_obj = imread(im_file)
```

Reading the image using PIL directly works better:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy
img = Image.open("test.gif")
img_arr = asarray(img.getdata(), dtype=numpy.uint8)
```

However, when reshaping the array, the following code does not work:

```
img_arr = img_arr.reshape(img.size[0], img.size[1], 3) #Note the number 3
```

The reason is that the actual color information is contained in a color table accessed through `img.getcolors()` or `img.getpalette()`.

Converting all the images to PNG or another suitable format that results in RGB images when opening them with `imread()` or `Image.open()` is not an option. I could convert the images when needed using PIL but I consider that solution ugly. So the question is as follows: Is there a simple and fast (the images are 5000 x 5000 pixels) way to convert the GIF images to RGB (in RAM) so that I can display them using `imshow()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the GIF to RGB first:

```
img = Image.open("test.gif").convert('RGB')
```

See this question: [Get pixel's RGB using PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064786/get-pixels-rgb-using-pil)