# wxpython get pixel color and saving images

Tags: wxpython

Python 3.3 and wxPython 3.0.

How do I get pixel color?  I haven't found any definitive answer yet that will work on Python 3.3.

Also, I have a drawing I have put on the screen and I want to save it.  Right now I just want to save as an RGB image, in the future I may want to add in the transparency factor as well.  First of all, what files types allow saving an image RGB and also what files allow the alpha channel to get saved as well?  Then how I go about saving the image?  I know it sounds like png/bmp may be the only ones that allows alpha, but maybe I have misunderstood what I've seen thus far.

Answer (score 0):

To get the pixel color value, you will want to use the Python Imaging Library. There's actually already several answers with the explanation here on Stack:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138250/read-the-rgb-value-of-a-given-pixel-in-python-programatically
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064786/get-pixels-rgb-using-pil

I think the png and bmp formats are probably the best bets for alpha channels.

Comment: Is it my understanding or is it not possible to use PIL in Python 3.3?  Do I just have to copy it from the 2.7 directory to the 3.3 directory to be able to use it?  From my understanding I didn't think you could use PIL, Gtk, Pycurl and quite a few other modules in Python 3.3.  Hence why I asked the question on getting the pixel color.  I've seen several write-ups about using PIL for getting the pixel color but what I said above may be 'screwing' with my mind.

Comment: The official PIL project hasn't been ported to Python 3. However, you can use the pillow fork on it: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.3.0

Comment: Okay I see I might have a bit of an issue to be dealt with.  I have both 2.7 and 3.3 installed on the computer.  When I go to install Pillow it is being referenced over to 2.7.  How do I get them into the 3.3 folder.  It won't let me do a simple copy and paste.

Comment: On Windows, you just grab the right installer. If you are installing from source, do something like this: /path/to/python33.py /path/to/pillow/setup.py install