# "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" when I was trying to use getpixel() in python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I was trying to run a python script (python 2.6) which contains the code as below

```
import Image

def is_grey_scale(img_path="lena.jpg"):
    im = Image.open(img_path)
    w,h = im.size
    for i in range(w):
        for j in range(h):
            r,g,b,_ = im.getpixel((i,j))
            if r != g != b:
                return False

    return True
```

It is reporting error as defined below.

```
r,g,b, _ = im.getpixel((i, j))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Can you please let me know what is the error here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The situation is as follows

You are trying to unpack result returned from `im.getpixel((i, j))` into 4 variables `r, g, b, _`.

For this to work, the `im.getpixel` has to return a list, a tuple or another iterable, which will provide just 4 values for the variables. Providing more or less makes a problem.

But in your case, the function `im.getpixel((i, j))` is returning an `int`, which is not by any means an iterable, so it complains.

Comment: Or you can try `a, b, c = 1` and you'll get a `TypeError`, like the answer suggests.

Comment: @msvalkon Your case is valid in your sample, but there you definitely return an iterable. But as Huu Nguyen notes, assign `a, b = 1` and you get `TypeError`

Comment: For completeness, if you want to access `r, b, g` values of a pixel, you have to convert the image to an RGB or RGBA image. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11064935/2297365) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the method is.

```
    def getpixel(self, xy):
        """
        Returns the pixel value at a given position.

        :param xy: The coordinate, given as (x, y).
        :returns: The pixel value.  If the image is a multi-layer image,
            this method returns a tuple.
```

Is your image a "multi-layer image" ? I assume its the same image used all over image processing Courses. [Lena on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna)