# “TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable” on gresycale image

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I have an image treatment program, where one of it's functions makes a contrast from the image the user chooses. But in the case of a greyscale image, I get the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\EduPython\App\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1456, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\megzari.nassim\Desktop\Projet Complet\Test 2.py", line 194, in use_contrast
    result = change_contrast(S2.get())
  File "C:\Users\megzari.nassim\Desktop\Projet Complet\Test 2.py", line 188, in change_contrast
    new_color = tuple(int(factor * (c-128) + 128) for c in color)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I tried reconverting the `color` variable into `RGB`, and it still doesn't work.

Here the bit of code from this error:

```
def change_contrast(level):

    img = Image.open(a)
    img.load()

    factor = (259 * (level+255)) / (255 * (259-level))
    for x in range(img.size[0]):
        for y in range(img.size[1]):
            color = img.getpixel((x, y))
            new_color = tuple(int(factor * (c-128) + 128) for c in color)
            img.putpixel((x, y), new_color)

    return img
```

In case you need the full code, here it is:

```
from tkinter import*
import tkinter as Tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog, DISABLED, messagebox as tkMessageBox
import os
import ntpath
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageFilter
import PIL
from collections import Counter
from random import randint
import random
import PIL.ImageOps


def EchelleDeGris():
    Ima2=Image.new("RGB",(z[0],z[1]))
    px=Ima1.load()
    px1=Ima2.load()
    for x in range(z[0]):
        for y in range(z[1]):
            p=px[x,y]
            if type(p)==int:
                p=(p,p,p)
            o=int((p[0]+p[1]+p[2])/3)
            px1[x,y]=(o,o,o)
    Ima2.save(""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\ImageMod.png")
    im2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\ImageMod.png")
    main.image = im2
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im2)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan =4)

def SupprimerImage():
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=imt)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan =4)

def Luminosite():
    Ima2=Image.new("RGB",(z[0],z[1]))
    px=Ima1.load()
    px1=Ima2.load()
    for x in range(z[0]):
        for y in range(z[1]):
            p=px[x,y]
            if type(p)==int:
                p=(p,p,p)
            px1[x,y]=(p[0]+S1.get(),p[1]+S1.get(),p[2]+S1.get())
    Ima2.save(""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\ImageMod.png")
    im2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\ImageMod.png")
    main.image = im2
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im2)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan =4)

def AnnulerModifications():
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im1)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan =4)

def get_pixel(pixels, x, y):
    try:
        return pixels[x, y]
    except IndexError:
        return None


def get_neighbors(pixels, x, y):
    neighbors = list()
    neighbors.append(get_pixel(pixels, x, y - 1))
    neighbors.append(get_pixel(pixels, x, y + 1))
    neighbors.append(get_pixel(pixels, x - 1, y))
    neighbors.append(get_pixel(pixels, x + 1, y))
    neighbors.append(get_pixel(pixels, x - 1, y - 1))
    neighbors.append(get_pixel(pixels, x - 1, y + 1))
    neighbors.append(get_pixel(pixels, x + 1, y - 1))
    neighbors.append(get_pixel(pixels, x + 1, y + 1))
    return neighbors


def filter_art(pixels, size):
    indexes = dict()
    for x in range(size[0]):
        for y in range(size[1]):
            color = get_pixel(pixels, x, y)
            neighbors = get_neighbors(pixels, x, y)
            new_color = Counter(neighbors).most_common()[0][0]
            if new_color is not None:
                indexes[x, y] = new_color
    for x, y in indexes:
        pixels[x, y] = indexes[x, y]


def pop_art(path_orig, path_mod, coef):

    s=[]
    for i in range(9):

        r=(randint(0,255), randint(0,255), randint(0,255))
        g=(randint(0,255), randint(0,255), randint(0,255))
        b=(randint(0,255), randint(0,255), randint(0,255))

        image_orig = Image.open(path_orig)
        size = image_orig.size
        image_mod = Image.new("RGB",(size[0],size[1]))
        pixels_orig = image_orig.load()
        pixels_mod = image_mod.load()
        for x in range(size[0]):
            for y in range(size[1]):
                p = pixels_orig[x, y]
                if isinstance(p, int):
                    rgb = (p,p,p)
                elif isinstance(p, tuple) and len(p) in (3, 4):
                    rgb = p[:3]
                else:
                    raise TypeError('Unknown pallete')
                average_color = sum(rgb) / 3
                if average_color <= 85:
                    pixels_mod[x, y] = r
                elif 85 < average_color <= 170:
                    pixels_mod[x, y] = g
                elif average_color > 170:
                    pixels_mod[x, y] = b
        for _ in range(coef):
            filter_art(pixels_mod, size)
        image_mod.save(''+dir_path+'\\PopArt\\Modified Images\\result'+str(i)+'.png')
        Img=[None]*9
    for i in range(9):
        Img[i]=Image.open(""+dir_path+"\\PopArt\\Modified Images\\result"+str(i)+".png")
        basewidth = int(Img[i].size[1]/3)
        wpercent = (basewidth / float(Img[i].size[0]))
        hsize = int((float(Img[i].size[1]) * float(wpercent )))
        Img[i] = Img[i].resize((basewidth , hsize ), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
        Img[i].save(''+dir_path+'\\PopArt\\Resized Images\\resized_image'+str(i)+'.png')


    Img1=[None]*9
    pixels1=[None]*9
    Imaz=Image.new("RGB",(basewidth*3,hsize*3))
    pixels=Imaz.load()
    for i in range(9):
        Img1[i]=Image.open(''+dir_path+'\\PopArt\\Resized Images\\resized_image'+str(i)+'.png')
        pixels1[i]=Img1[i].load()


    for x in range(0,basewidth):
        for y in range(0,hsize):
            pixels[x,y]=pixels1[0][x,y]
        for y in range(hsize,hsize*2):
            pixels[x,y]=pixels1[1][x,y-hsize]
        for y in range(hsize*2,hsize*3):
            pixels[x,y]=pixels1[2][x,y-hsize*2]

    for x in range(basewidth,basewidth*2):
        for y in range(0,hsize):
            pixels[x,y]=pixels1[3][x-basewidth,y]
        for y in range(hsize,hsize*2):
            pixels[x,y]=pixels1[4][x-basewidth,y-hsize]
        for y in range(hsize*2,hsize*3):
            pixels[x,y]=pixels1[5][x-basewidth,y-hsize*2]

    for x in range(basewidth*2,basewidth*3):
        for y in range(0,hsize):
            pixels[x,y]=pixels1[6][x-basewidth*2,y]
        for y in range(hsize,hsize*2):
            pixels[x,y]=pixels1[7][x-basewidth*2,y-hsize]
        for y in range(hsize*2,hsize*3):
            pixels[x,y]=pixels1[8][x-basewidth*2,y-hsize*2]
    Imaz = Imaz.resize((size[0] , size[1] ), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
    Imaz.save(""+dir_path+"\\PopArt\\Result Image\\result.png")


def usepop():
    im2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\traitement.png")
    main.image = im2
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im2)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan =4)
    I2.update_idletasks()
    pop_art(a, None, coef=4)
    im2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=""+dir_path+"\\PopArt\\Result Image\\result.png")
    main.image = im2
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im2)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan =4)

def change_contrast(level):

    img = Image.open(a)
    img.load()

    factor = (259 * (level+255)) / (255 * (259-level))
    for x in range(img.size[0]):
        for y in range(img.size[1]):
            color = img.getpixel((x, y))
            new_color = tuple(int(factor * (c-128) + 128) for c in color)
            img.putpixel((x, y), new_color)

    return img

def use_contrast():
    result = change_contrast(S2.get())
    result.save(""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\ImageMod.png")
    im2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\ImageMod.png")
    main.image = im2
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im2)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan =4)

def recherche_contours():
    Ima2=Image.new("RGB",(z[0],z[1]))
    px=Ima1.load()
    px1=Ima2.load()
    for x in range(z[0]):
        for y in range(z[1]):
            p=px[x,y]
            if type(p)==int:
                p=(p,p,p)
            o=int((p[0]+p[1]+p[2])/3)
            px1[x,y]=(o,o,o)
    Ima2 = Ima2.filter(ImageFilter.FIND_EDGES)
    image = Ima2
    if image.mode == 'RGBA':
        r,g,b,a = image.split()
        rgb_image = Image.merge('RGB', (r,g,b))

        inverted_image = PIL.ImageOps.invert(rgb_image)

        r2,g2,b2 = inverted_image.split()

        final_transparent_image = Image.merge('RGBA', (r2,g2,b2,a))

        final_transparent_image.save(""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\ImageMod.png")

    else:
        inverted_image = PIL.ImageOps.invert(image)
        inverted_image.save(""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\ImageMod.png")
    im2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\ImageMod.png")
    main.image = im2
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im2)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan =4)

main=Tk()

main.withdraw()
a = filedialog.askopenfilename()
main.deiconify()

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath("Test2.py"))

main.configure(background="#a1dbcd")
main.title("Photoshop Version.Megzari")

Ima1=Image.open(a)
z=Ima1.size
nux=Image.new("RGB",(z[0],z[1]))
nuxy=nux.load()
for x in range(z[0]):
    for y in range(z[1]):
        nuxy[x,y]=(255,255,255)
nux.save(""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\Blank.png")


if z>(400,400):
    main.withdraw()
    tkMessageBox.showinfo( "Resolution Error", "The image is too big, please select a smaller one.")
    sys.exit()


elif z<(400,400):
    im1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=a)
    I1 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im1)
    I1.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan =3)
    imt = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\Blank.png")
    T1 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=imt)
    T1.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan =4)
    B1 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Echelle de gris", command = EchelleDeGris, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39", state=NORMAL)
    B1.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=1, column=0)
    B3 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Appliquer Luminosité", command = Luminosite, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39")
    B3.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=1, column=1)
    S1 = Scale(main, from_=0, to=254, orient=HORIZONTAL, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39", length = 200)
    S1.grid(row=2, column=1)
    B2 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Supprimer Image", command = SupprimerImage, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39")
    B2.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=1, column=7)
    B3 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Annuler Modifications", command = AnnulerModifications, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39")
    B3.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=1, column=6)
    B4 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Pop Art", command = usepop, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39")
    B4.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=1, column=3)
    S2 = Scale(main, from_=-258, to=258, orient=HORIZONTAL, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39", length = 200)
    S2.grid(row=2, column=4)
    B4 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Appliquer Contraste", command = use_contrast, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39")
    B4.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=1, column=4)
    B5 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Trouver Contours", command = recherche_contours, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39")
    B5.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=1, column=5)

    s=S1.get()
    s2=S2.get()





main.mainloop()
```

EDIT: I tried using:

```
if type(color)==int:
    color=(color,color,color)
```

and it required me an integer on the `new_color`

Comment: you just asked this and it got marked as duplicate, why are you asking again?

Comment: You just asked this 2 minutes ago and it was linked to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064786/get-pixels-rgb-using-pil. Didn't the linked question answer yours?

Comment: No it has nothing to do with mine. I have a specific problem with greyscale images giving me the error above, and not the colored ones. I have a whole code using the PIL RGB extraction from images so what's the point in linking it to my post ?

Comment: Okay, in general, you should've added a comment in the previous question asking the person who closed it to re-open it, not ask again. What's done is done now and since you deleted the old question I guess there's no real issue.

Comment: I've never had a post closed so I didn't know it worked like that. I'll think about it next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one could answer this simple question, I found out myself after a bunch of tests and maneuvers.
In fact, all I had to do was check the `type()` of `color`. If it is an `int`, I make `color` a tuple. You can do this by either assigning: `color=(color,color,color)` or making it a list this way: `color=[color,color,color]` or `color=[color]*3` then making it tuple: `color=tuple(color)`. Since `new_color` will be now a tuple, its still 3 identical values, but `img.putpixel((x, y), new_color)` requires an integer, so you just extract the first value of `new_color` by writing `new_color=new_color[0]`. If `type()` of `color` is not an int, you just run the other piece of code without any modification. Here is the working code of the one up above:

```
def change_contrast(level):

    img = Image.open(a)
    img.load()

    factor = (259 * (level+255)) / (255 * (259-level))
    for x in range(img.size[0]):
        for y in range(img.size[1]):
            color = img.getpixel((x, y))
            if type(color) == int:
                color=(color,color,color)
                new_color = tuple(int(factor * (c-128) + 128) for c in color)
                new_color = new_color[0]
                img.putpixel((x, y), new_color)
            elif type(color) != int:
                new_color = tuple(int(factor * (c-128) + 128) for c in color)
                img.putpixel((x, y), new_color)
    return img
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pil/image-constructors.html#image-methods):

> **.getpixel(xy)**
>
> Returns the pixel value or values at the given coordinates. For  single-band images, returns a single number; a sequence of pixel
>   values is returned for multi-band images. For example, if the top left
>   pixel of an image im of mode "L" has value 128, then
>   im.getpixel((0,0)) returns 128.

So, it can return either a single value or a tuple. If it's a single value, you'll get the `not iterable` error. That means you have to check what you get from the call.

Comment: I know that. In case you didn't notice, my other functions have `if type(p)==int:` then it makes it a tuple `p=(p,p,p)`. It might not be the best way to do it, but it works for my other functions, so when I use it on a greyscale image, it displays what I expect. But in my contrast function it doesn't work. I also tried `.convert("RGB")`, still no result.

Comment: Ok, that means that you already know what the problem is: you're getting an int instead of a tuple and you cannot iterate on an int. Just use the same logic if that works for you. I wouldn't do it because in `change_contrast` you're not even checking if it's single band mode `L` or `P` but as I said, it's ok if that works in your case.

Comment: That doesn't help. I know my photos are `RGB` or `RGBA`, with only `.png` files. So why should I check if it's a single band mode `L` or `P` ?