# How to split image into rows python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a rectangular image. I need a way to use PIL or OpenCV to split it into sections of x many pixels tall. I have looked at the forms but all I could find are things to split into tiles. Does anybody know how to accomplish this?

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Here's how you read pixels: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064786/get-pixels-rgb-using-pil. That should be enough info to create rows of pixels.

Comment: Use the crop method. It returns a new image so you can crop the same image many times to get each row

Comment: what is difference between `tiles` and `"sections of x many pixels tall"` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that does what you asked:
The `split_into_rows` function does all the actual splitting, and is a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). It repeatedly uses the crop method to extract rectangular sections from the image and yield them.

```
from PIL import Image
import os

im = Image.open('input_image.png')

def split_into_rows(im, row_height):
    y = 0
    print(im.height)
    while y < im.height:
        top_left = (0, y)
        bottom_right = (im.width, min(y + row_height, im.height))
        yield im.crop((*top_left, *bottom_right))

        y += row_height

OUTPUT_DIR = 'output'

for i, row in enumerate(split_into_rows(im, 400)):
    save_path = os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, f'{i}.png')

    row.save(save_path)
    print(i)
```