# Is there a way to get an RGB value of a pixel on a frame of a GIF in PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am currently working on a discord bot with Pycord. I am working on adding support for GIF images on the currently existing image commands, and I need the color of the pixels. When I try to get the color of an exact point in PIL/Pillow, I get a number representing the color of the pixel in the GIF color table, which is not what I want. Even when I convert the image to RGBA, I still get only the index, nothing else. When I google it, all I see is multitudes of this same method that I tried.

Here is a basic program to demonstrate what I have tried:

```py
from io import BytesIO as toimg
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw, ImageOps, ImageSequence
      #reqdata is gif data from a url
      imggif = Image.open(toimg(reqdata.content))
      for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(imggif):
        img = frame.convert("RGBA")
        img = img.convert("RGBA") # might not need this due to the line above but idk
        img = ImageOps.grayscale(img) # this line was not here before, edited it in.
        width, height = img.size
        for y in range(height):
          for x in range(width):
            print(img.getpixel((x,y))) # this prints out only one number, i need an RGBA value (4 numbers)
```

If anyone can help, that would be very appreciated!

Edit: I found out the solution and I realized that it was not the frame itself, but instead it was because I grayscaled the image after converting it. The program was created based on what I thought was the mistake, and I didn't even check it! This was nowhere in the question and i apologize for not thinking to look at such a simple thing before posting this question. I had to convert back to RGBA after grayscaling the image. :(

Edit 2: I am just now realizing that this is going to be my very last question, and that I should have looked further to realize my incredibly simple mistake before wasting my last chance on this site i will ever have. It's for the better, I'm a dumbass who is unable to realize such simple things. I will not be and have not been needed on this site.

Comment: I just tried your code with a 24 frame animated GIF file, and `getpixel` always returned a 4 element tuple.  The only difference is that I used a file rather than a byte sequence from a URL.

Comment: I just retried this by reading the entire file and passing it to `toimg` just as you did, and it still worked perfectly.  If you expect some help, you'll need to produce code that allows *anyone* to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I literally just found out that it was the grayscaling that i didn't suspect/mention once in this question... Apologies for wasting everyones time over this mistake.

Comment: That was an important detail to leave out.  You could have had an answer immediately.

Comment: I am now aware, and I apologize once again for leaving such an important detail out of the question

Comment: Personally I accept your apology - mistakes happen.  Can't speak for anybody else though.

Comment: No need to be discouraged by a simple mistake - I would imagine you'd be more careful next time.

Comment: But now there is no "next time" because of that simple mistake.

Comment: But the only reason there's no "next time" is because you choose it, right?  You haven't been banned or anything, have you?  If you ask another question, and it's a good one, nobody will remember or care about this one.

Comment: I've reached "the question limit" like, 3 times now. This time there was a notification saying that "some of my questions in the past were not well recieved, and i'm in danger of not being able to ask any more." Now I cannot ask any more questions on this account. I am also not knowledgeable enough in coding to answer questions, so I basically just threw this account in the trash.

Comment: None of your questions have a negative score, so I'm baffled why you'd get that message.  Have you actually tried to post another question and been rejected?  You might get a reprieve by deleting some of those "not well received" questions - I've seen a lot of people do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```py
r, g, b, a = img.getpixel((x, y))
```

I tested this and it works for me. Based on [this post].
([Get pixel's RGB using PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064786/get-pixels-rgb-using-pil))

Edit: another approach that has worked for me in the past is to use `pixels = img.load()` and index a pixel like `pixels[x, y]`

Comment: I got a typeerror with "cannot unpack non-iterable int object."

Comment: @3DG my experience matches this answer as well.  If it isn't working for you, then you didn't convert the image to RGBA as you claimed in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```py
    from PIL import Image
    
    red_image = Image.open("red.png")
    red_image_rgb = red_image.convert("RGB")
    rgb_pixel_value = red_image_rgb.getpixel((10,15))
    print(rgb_pixel_value) #Prints (255, 0, 0)
```

Comment: I'm not trying to get a pixel of a PNG image, I'm trying to get a pixel out of a GIF frame.

Comment: I just tried it with a GIF and it got an RGB Value.