# PIL won't load RGB Image

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am trying to load this image into python (I provided a link because its 75mb): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1usiKRN1JQaIxTTo_HTXPwUj8LeyR8CDc/view?usp=sharing

My current code is below, it loads the image and when you `png.show()` the image it displays it in RBG but when converted to a numpy array its shape is only (h, w) not (h, w, 3) for RGB.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = 233280000

png = Image.open('world.png')
png.show()
png = np.array(png)

print(png.shape)
```

Comment: So PIL *does* load the RGB image, but `np.array` does something unexpected, right?

Comment: Yes, that is what is happening.

Comment: Then the title is wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064786/get-pixels-rgb-using-pil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = 233280000

png = Image.open('world.png').convert('RGB')
png.show()
png = np.array(png)

print(png.shape)
```