# How to get pixel coordinates if I know color(RGB)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, python-imaging-library

I use Python, opencv and PIL.

```
image = cv2.imread('image.jpg')

color = (235, 187, 7)
```

How can I get pixel coordinates(x, y) if I know pixels color?

Comment: JPEG is lossy. Good luck with that.

Comment: Ok ill use PNG thx. need pixelsearch

Comment: use `cv2.inRange()`, see [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html) for e.g.

Comment: This answer shows how to do it simply and quickly... https://stackoverflow.com/a/51091479/2836621

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds `cv2.inRange()` will help if you want pixels within a certain range. Here OP wants all coordinates for a particular pixel color.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a numpythonic solution. Numpy library speeds up operations wherever possible.

- Assuming the color to be: `color = (235, 187, 7)`

`indices = np.where(img == color)`

- I used the numpy.where() method to retrieve a tuple indices of two arrays where the first array contains the x-coordinates of the pixels of color (235, 187, 7) and the second array contains the y-coordinates of those pixels.

Now `indices` returns something like the following:

```
(array([ 81,  81,  81, ..., 304, 304, 304], dtype=int64),
 array([317, 317, 317, ..., 520, 520, 520], dtype=int64),
 array([0, 1, 2, ..., 0, 1, 2], dtype=int64))
```

- I then used the zip() method to get a list of tuples containing those points.

`coordinates = zip(indices[0], indices[1])`

- But if you notice since this is a color image with three channels each coordinate will be repeated thrice. We have to keep only the unique coordinates. This can be accomplished using `set()` method.

`unique_coordinates = list(set(list(coordinates)))`

Answer (score 4):

Try something like:

```
color = (235, 187, 7)
im = Image.open('image.gif')
rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')
for x in range(rgb_im.size()[0]):
    for y in range(rgb_im.size()[1]):
        r, g, b = rgb_im.getpixel((x, y))
        if (r,g,b) == colour:
            print(f"Found {colour} at {x},{y}!")
```

But [getpixel can be slow](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.getpixel), so look at using [pixel access objects](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.load).

Also note that the value returned can depend on the image type.  For example, a single value is returned with `pix[1, 1]` because GIF pixels refer to one of the 256 values in the GIF color palette.

See also this SO post: [Python and PIL pixel values different for GIF and JPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800009/python-and-pil-pixel-values-different-for-gif-and-jpeg) and this [PIL Reference page](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm)  contains more information on the `convert()` function.

By the way, your code would work just fine for `.jpg` images.

Answer (score 2):

you can use following:

```
    import numpy as np

    # for color image
    color = (75, 75, 75)
    pixels = np.argwhere(img == color)
```

output(it repeats the same coordinates three times(number of colors)):

```
[[   0   28    0]
 [   0   28    1]
 [   0   28    2]
 [   0   54    0]
 [   0   54    1]
 [   0   54    2]
 ................]
```

to avoid it do following(sorry for code readability):

```
    pixels = pixels[::3][:, [0, 1]]
```

output:

```
[[   0   28]
 [   0   54]
 ...........]
```

for gray scale image it looks better:

```
    color = (75)
    pixels = np.argwhere(img == color)
```

output:

```
[[   0   28]
 [   0   54]
 ...........]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import PIL #The reason I use PIL and not opencv is that I find pillow 
#(which is imported with 'PIL') a very useful library for image editing.

image = PIL.Image.open('Name_image') #the image is opened and named image
f = image.load() #I'm not sure what the load() operation exactly does, but it 
# is necesarry.

color = (235, 187, 7) # the Red Green Blue values that you want to find the 
#coordinates of
PixelCoordinates = [] # List in which all pixel coordinates that match 
#requirements will be added.

#The lines of code below check for each pixel in the image if the RGB-values 
# are equal to (235, 187, 7)
for x in image.size[0]:
    for y in image.size[1]:
        if f[x,y] == color:
            PixelCoordinates.append([x,y])
```

Comment: Consider adding some explanation of the code. Also, the question uses opencv, so try to say why did you choose PIL.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using cv2 library only

```py
import cv2

blue = int(input("Enter blue value: "))
green = int(input("Enter green value: "))
red = int(input("Enter red value: "))
path = str(input("Enter image path with image extension:"))
img = cv2.imread(path)
img= cv2.resize(img,(150,150))
x,y,z = img.shape

for i in range(x):
  for j in range(y):
    if img[i,j,0]==blue & img[i,j,1]==green & img[i,j,1]==red:
      print("Found color at ",i,j)
```